# GatsbyJs how to add comma after each tag name but not for last one

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to format my tags name by adding a comma after each tag, but i couldn't make it by now. I've tried `{node.name.length- 1 ? ', ' : ''}` but it didn't work

Thank's for your help :)

here's my code :

```
  
            <p>{wpPost.date}</p>
            <div>
                 {wpPost.tags.nodes.map((node)=> {
                        return (
                            <Link to={`/blog/tag/${node.slug}`}>
                            <h3> {node.name} </h3>
                            </Link>
                            
                        )
                    })}
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
{ wpPost.tags.nodes.map((node, index) => (
  { index > 0 ? ',&nbsp;' : '' }
  <Link to={`/blog/tag/${node.slug}`}>
    <h3> {node.name} </h3>
  </Link>
) }
```

Note that I use `&nbsp;` instead of   due to   probably occupying a zero width in the display, while [&nbsp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) is made for explicitly occupying one space